# What is the proper plural of “a series”?

Tags: grammatical-number, word-usage, possessives, latin, defective-nouns

In math, we use the term *series* a lot, and there are many types of *series*.

How should I craft my sentence when I have three different ones in mind to talk about? Should I settle down for a less mortal alternative of “list of series” or something like that?

The existing question on [The possessive and plural forms of “series”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10166/possessive-and-plural-of-series)  suggests the usage of *series’*. But is that all?

If that’s the only solution, then could you please explain the usage of apostrophe symbol at the end?  Is that a plural marker or a possessive marker, or both?

Comment: I fail to see where in the linked question it suggests that the plural of *series* were *series'*. It only does so for the *possessive*. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/series#Noun), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/series), and the [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/series) all say that the plural is "series". You yourself have just written, "I have 3 different series in mind". I am not sure what questions are still left.

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道 Moreover, the true reason for why the plural and/or possessive of nouns like *species* and *series* must be invariant is quite interesting, and merits discussion. See my comment to John.

Comment: What a **dumb reason to close** a question. Stack Exchange is a reference. Whether it was first is no impediment to being best. In fact, the top two results googling ["plural of series"](https://www.google.com/search?q=plural+of+series) are stack exchange articles. Except now one of them can't be given new answers because it's been stuffily closed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Series* (like *deer, salmon,* and *sheep*) is pronounced and spelled the same in the plural as in the singular. If either the singular or the plural is used as a possessive, an apostrophe is added to show that in print, though there is no pronunciation difference in speech.  Thus,

- *The series doesn't converge.* (singular)
- *The series don't converge.* (plural)
- *This series' limit is unknown.*  (singular possessive)
- *These series' limits are unknown*. (plural possessive)

More examples can be seen [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/EulersFormula.pdf).

Comment: This is true, but for quite different reasons. Terms of venery—game animals we hunt—are often invariant: elk,deer,bison. In the case of *series*, we have the phonological suppression of any /ɨz/ inflectional suffix, whether for plural or possessive or both, on all nouns **already ending in /iːz/:** *series, species, Diogenes, Achilles, Archimedes*. This is the real law that underlies the unexplained hand-wavy rule about classical possessives, like *Achilles’ tendon*. Other examples: *1 species is, 2 species are, 1 species’ name is, 2 species’ names are.* Completely invariant in pronunciation.

Comment: @tchrist Hmm, you say there are two different reasons, but then you don't give a reason for the first case. WHY are names of game animals unchanged in the plural? Do you know? Now that you bring it up, it's an interesting question.

Comment: Nobody really knows why; and it's not only beasts of venery -- _sheep_ also has a Zero plural, but _bear, wolf, and crow_ don't. And _species, series,_ etc. are all Greek and Latin words, borrowed intact with the Greek and Latin plurals (if any), which are all invariant ([Fifth Declension nouns](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LatinNouns.pdf) for the most part).

Comment: Possessive is another matter, since English only borrowed nominative forms. Proper names that end in /s/ or /z/ are rather peculiar when it comes to adding plural {-Z₁} and possessive {-Z₂} suffixes, and that shows up in print, too; consider _the Joneses, the Joneses' cat, Protagoras's Principle,_ etc.

Comment: @JohnLawler It’s not just the adding of an /ɨz/ inflection; it’s that you only ever get *one* of them no matter whether it’s possessive or plural, so plural possessives still have just one /ɨz/, and that the rare /iːz/ nouns can take zero /ɨz/ inflections, whereas the rest can take one but not two. Historically possessive /ɨz/ was also suppressed in the formulaic *for goodness’ sake, for conscience’ sake, for righteousness’ sake*. Unrelatedly, remember also the old *in speciē* and *in seriē*, which were ablative singulars of *speciēs* and *seriēs*. I think *specie* may still be used for money.

Comment: It’s somewhat odd that English kept the 5th-declension’s *-s* in the singulars for *series* and *species*, because the Romance languages did not. There *serie* (with appropriate diacritics as needed) is singular and *series* is plural: ES: una serie, unas series FR: une série, des séries.

Comment: I found another that works like *series* and *species* in that it ends in unstressed /iːz/, but which is not Greek like *Diogenes*.  It is *caries*, meaning “decay of the bones and teeth”, again from the Latin *-s* declension: *cariēs*. It is occasionally seen as a count noun. Grepping the OED also yielded the technical term *facies* < L. *faciēs*, which also has an invariant plural. Another is the *herpes* virus, although that may not be a count noun. There’s also a rare medical term *macies*, meaning emaciation; *nares* and *nates* are already plural, while *paries* has pl. *parietes*.

Comment: Don't forget _feces_.